# VBA - find values in columns and insert blank rows in front of those cells

Tags: vba, excel, insert

I want to find cells, which contain an exact value and insert in front of those cells blank rows. I already have code, which will find and insert those rows, but only behind those cells.

The code is here:

```
Private Sub SearchnInsertRows()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range, C As Range
Dim vR(), n As Long


With Worksheets("INPUT_2") ' <-- here should be the Sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column A
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) ' set the dynamic range to be searched

    ' loop through all cells in column A and copy below's cell to sheet "Output_2"
    For Each C In rng
        If C.Value = "Workflow" Then
            .Range(Cells(C.Row + 1, 1), Cells(C.Row + 8, 8)).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next C


End With

End Sub
```

This code will add 8 rows behind all cells, which contain word "Workflow", but I cannot figure it out, how to put them in front of cells "Workflow"

I thought, that when I put - instead of +, it should solve it, but when I change this line this way:

```
.Range(Cells(C.Row - 1, 1), Cells(C.Row - 8, 8)).EntireRow.Insert
```

and run it, the excel will stuck and still adding rows.

Could I ask you for an advice, what do I do incorrectly, please?

Many thanks

Comment: Instead of an `Each` loop use a `For i = LastRow to 1 Step -1` loop to loop from last row to first. Inserting/deleting rows has always to be done backwards (from bottom to top). To insert rows before a specific row you can use `.Insert xlShiftDown` to tell if the active row should shift down or up (see [Range.Insert Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-insert-method-excel)).

Comment: Thanks for you advice! I've tried to change the part beginnig `For Each`  it -  `For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If rng.Cells.Value = "Workflow" Then
            .Cells("A").EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i` and now I am getting error msg _Type mismatch_ on that line `.Cells("A").EntireRow.Insert`. What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: You didn't use `.Cells` correctly you need to specify a row and column like `.Cells(row, column)` or instead use `.Rows(i)`. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an `For Each` loop use a `For i = LastRow to 1 Step -1` loop to loop backwards from last row to first. Inserting or deleting rows has always to be done backwards (from bottom to top) because then it will only affect rows that are already processed otherwise the row-counts of unprocessed rows will change and mess up the loop.

Something like the following should work:

```
Option Explicit 'Very first line in a module to enforce correct variable declaring.

Private Sub SearchAndInsertRows()
    Dim lRow As Long, iRow As Long

    With Worksheets("INPUT_2") ' <-- here should be the Sheet's name
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column A

        'loop backwards (bottom to top = Step -1) through all rows
        For iRow = lRow To 1 Step -1
            'check if column A of current row (iRow) is "Workflow"
            If .Cells(iRow, "A").Value = "Workflow" Then
                .Rows(iRow).Resize(RowSize:=8).Insert xlShiftDown
                  'insert 8 rows and move current (iRow) row down (xlShiftDown)
                  'means: insert 8 rows ABOVE current row (iRow)

                '.Rows(iRow + 1).Resize(RowSize:=8).Insert xlShiftDown
                   'alternatively use .Rows(iRow + 1) to insert BELOW current row (iRow)
            End If
        Next iRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I see, now I get it. Btw. the code works correctly. Thank you very much!